# Can non-market installed app users post reviews and ratings?

Tags: android, google-play

I have users with my Android app installed from non-market install (manual apk install)

Will they be able to post star ratings and review comments on the Android Play market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

But at least I have to have 30 characters ... For me it didn't work.